# Create a sequence of numbers with breaks

Tags: r

I want to create a sequence of numbers like this:

```
X=22+1
Y=x+2
Z=x+3
A=x+4
B=X+5

1,2,X,3,4,Y,5,6,Z,7,8,A,10,11,B #and so on...
1,2,23,3,4,25,5,6,26,7,8,27,10,11,28  #and so on...
```

How do this with R? there's a function to do this?

Comment: i edited the post

Comment: my intention is not create a normal sequence like 1,2,3,4,5 but a sequence that inserts a number in the 1,2,3,4,5 sequence like 1,2,8,3,4,9,5.

Comment: I created an example with solution.  Please check if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do

```
unlist(Map(c, split(v1, as.integer(gl(length(v1), 2, 
      length(v1)))), c(X, Y, Z, A, B)), use.names = FALSE)
#[1]  1  2 23  3  4 25  5  6 26  7  8 27  9 10 28
```

#### data

```
v1 <- 1:10
X <- 23
Y <- X + 2
Z <- X + 3
A <- X + 4
B <- X + 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a duplicated record at specific position and replace them with another sequence.

```
seq1 <- 1:10
seq2 <- c(23, 25:28)
seq3 <- sort(c(seq1, seq(2, 10, 2)))
seq3[duplicated(seq3)] <- seq2
seq3
#[1]  1  2 23  3  4 25  5  6 26  7  8 27  9 10 28
```